# Excel VBA - pass name of class method to another subroutine to call the method

Tags: excel, function, oop, user-defined-functions, vba

I have an add-in file named "MyFunctions.xlam".  This contains several helper functions, including custom solvers, etc.

In MyFunctions, I have a Class named "ChemicalRelease".  This class has a property of massRate and a public function named "affectedArea".  The "affectedArea" method goes thru several calculations and method calls to determine the affected area size of a chemical release, based on a provided mass rate and several other factors.  I have a target affected area size, and am looking to use a solver to back calculate an appropriate mass rate that would result in the target affected area size.

Inside of the ChemicalRelease Class Module, a method named "varyMassRateForTargArea" attempts to solve for massRate using the secant solver, targeting a specified affected area:

massRate = solverSecant(massRate, "ChemicalRelease.affectedArea", targArea, 0, False)

"solverSecant" is in "Module1" of "MyFunctions", and is meant to be generic enough to be used by any class method.

Here is some code for "solverSecant":

```
Function solverSecant(ByRef varyingProperty, methodToRun, Optional yTarget = 0#, Optional dx = 0, Optional dDebug As Boolean = False)

x0 = varyingProperty

If dx <= 0 Then dx = x0 / 1000

maxIter = 1000

currIter = 0

xTol = dx / 10

x1 = x0 + dx

x0 = varyingProperty
y0 = Application.Run(methodToRun) - yTarget
...
```

the "solverSecant" method needs to do the following:

1. update the property value for massRate in the instantiated ChemicalRelease object.
2. run the object's "affectedArea" method with the updated property value from step #1.
3. do the rest of the solver algorithm, but that part should work ok, given that the other two requirements are met.

My questions are:

1. Once an instance of "ChemicalRelease" is initialized, and the "varyMassRateForTargArea" method is called, is it possible to pass the reference to the instantiated "ChemicalRelease" object from "varyMassRateForTargArea" to "solverSecant" in "Module1"?  This would be equivalent of sending "self" as an argument in every other language I can think of.
2. Is there some way to run the "ChemicalRelease.affectedArea" method from "Module1"?  I can't seem to get it to work with "Application.Run", but I may not have the syntax correct.

Thank you for your help.  I understand that I can have the solver as part of a method in the class object, but I'd rather develop a solver in the "MyFunctions" that can apply it to any other method/property of other classes.

Comment: You should be able to pass `Me` from the class to other code.  And to call `affectedArea` use `ClassInstanceName.affectedArea` (provided affectedArea is public)

Comment: Thanks!  I thought I tried to pass “Me”, but maybe I didn’t properly type it in the called function. I will try again in the morning.

Comment: chris neilsen - Passing "Me" as an argument worked well.  How do I pass reference to the ClassInstanceName.affectedArea method so that it can be run in the called function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `Me` from the class to other code. And to call `affectedArea` use `ClassInstanceName.affectedArea` (provided `affectedArea` is public)

To Demonstrate, create class `ChemicalRelease` as

```
Option Explicit

Private pVar As Variant

Property Get affectedArea() As Variant
    affectedArea = pVar
End Property

Sub Init(v As Variant)
    pVar = v
End Sub

Sub varyMassRateForTargArea()
    Module1.solverSecant Me
End Sub

Sub Method1(v As Variant)
    Debug.Print "Method 1", v
End Sub

Sub Method2(v As Variant)
    Debug.Print "Method 2", v
End Sub
```

In `Module1` code this

```
Option Explicit

Sub solverSecant(obj As ChemicalRelease)
    Dim NameOfMethod As String
    Debug.Print "solverSecant", obj.affectedArea

    NameOfMethod = "Method1"
    CallByName obj, NameOfMethod, VbMethod, "Parameter passed to Method 1"
    NameOfMethod = "Method2"
    CallByName obj, NameOfMethod, VbMethod, "Parameter passed to Method 2"
End Sub
```

Run this Test code to demonstarte actions

```
Sub Test()
    Dim Instance1OfClass As ChemicalRelease, Instance2OfClass As ChemicalRelease
    Dim v

    Set Instance1OfClass = New ChemicalRelease
    Set Instance2OfClass = New ChemicalRelease

    Instance1OfClass.Init "A"
    Instance2OfClass.Init "B"

    ' Get Property
    v = Instance1OfClass.affectedArea
    Debug.Print "Instance1OfClass", v

    v = Instance2OfClass.affectedArea
    Debug.Print "Instance2OfClass", v

    ' Call method
    Instance1OfClass.varyMassRateForTargArea
    Instance2OfClass.varyMassRateForTargArea
End Sub
```

Output in immediate window should be

> Instance1OfClass            A
>   Instance2OfClass            B
>   solverSecant  A
>   Method 1      Parameter passed to Method 1
>   Method 2      Parameter passed to Method 2
>   solverSecant  B
>   Method 1      Parameter passed to Method 1
>   Method 2      Parameter passed to Method 2

Comment: Thank you.  In solverSecant, you explicitly call obj.affectedArea.  How do I pass reference to solverSecant of the "affectedArea" method?  I'm looking to have solverSecant run any provided method of an instantiated class without having to explicitly state the name of the method in solverSecant.

Comment: Thank you!  I didn’t know about CallByName.